# Approaching SQL query building

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm unsure what method to use in creating a query. Each week I need to pull a Count of invoices grouped by status types and the most recent Invoice entered.

I have many vendor tables that store sales records and I create a report each week that pulls the following.

```
Select Invoice_status, COUNT(Invoice_status) As Total, Max(Invoice_date)
From VendorABCRecordsTable
Group By Invoice_Status
```

Results for each vendor

```
|Invoice_status| Total | column3
```

I run this for VendorABCRecordsTable, Vendor123RecordsTable, VendorXYZRecordsTable and copy paste the results to a spread sheet.

How would I write it so the results would come out

```
Vendor     | Invoice_status | Total | column3
VendorABC  |
Vendor123  |
VendorXYZ  |
```

Comment: Why do you 'have many vendor tables'? Why not one vendor table? Most likely your db is not properly normalized and that is source of your aggravation. Question is too broad and there is no code for analysis and therefore not suited to SO. Perhaps a UNION query would help you deal with this poor design.

Comment: A single vendor table will make your life way easier.

Comment: Rule no 3 of data engineering. Never, never, design a database so you must add a table when you add a person (like a customer or a vendor). You want your system to serve many thousands of people, right? Thousands of tables? Not good.

Comment: I've been here a few months. If i get assigned the task of restructuring their entire system I'll offer up my opinions.

Comment: If one of the answer resolved issue, please mark accepted. Can upvote as many as want.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not optimized schema. However, perhaps a UNION query will help you deal with this.

```
SELECT *, "ABC" AS Vendor FROM VendorABCRecordsTable
UNION SELECT *, "123" FROM Vendor123RecordsTable
UNION SELECT *, "XYZ" FROM VendorXYZRecordsTable;
```

In order to use the * wildcard, fields must be in same order and same data types and same number of fields in table design. Otherwise, explicitly list fields in each SELECT. There is a limit of 50 SELECT lines. First SELECT line defines field names and data types.

Now use that query in subsequent queries.

Cannot edit data via UNION query.

Could specify fields to do aggregate calcs and grouping in each SELECT line. However, building UNION with raw data provides a dataset that can serve as source for various manipulations of data. This UNION is essentially what properly designed table would be like.

Comment: This answered helped me get closer to the code I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   'VendorABC'            Vendor
  ,Invoice_status
  ,COUNT(Invoice_status)  Total
  ,MAX(Invoice_date)      MaxInvoiceDate
 from VendorABCRecordsTable
 group by Invoice_Status
UNION ALL SELECT
   'Vendor123'            Vendor
  ,Invoice_status
  ,COUNT(Invoice_status)  Total
  ,MAX(Invoice_date)      MaxInvoiceDate
 from Vendor123RecordsTable
 group by Invoice_Status
UNION ALL SELECT
   'VendorXYZ'            Vendor
  ,Invoice_status
  ,COUNT(Invoice_status)  Total
  ,MAX(Invoice_date)      MaxInvoiceDate
 from VendorXYZRecordsTable
 group by Invoice_Status
```

Note, `UNION ALL`, as there will be no duplicate rows.  If it needs to be ordered somehow, add an `ORDER BY` clause to (only!) the last query. (And you can name it as "Column3", if necessary.)

Comment: Thank you! This was what the doctor ordered. I wanted to use union all but it felt clunky after I added all 30 vendors. It gets the job done so no complaints here!

Comment: Good to hear it! For all Stack Overflow posts (not just this one), please upvote answers that helped you, and/or mark them as Accepted.